# Generating vector with normal distribution of entires in java

Tags: java, random

I would like to create a vector with the entries filled with normal distribution of data.How could I do it in java?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague.  But you probably want to use [`Random.nextGaussian()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29).